# Why does this shader to draw a triangle in opengl not get run multiple times

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I am learning to use OpenGL through some youtube tutorials online. At 24:43 is the code I am talking about: [https:
//www.youtube.com/watch?v=71BLZwRGUJE&list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2&index=7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71BLZwRGUJE&list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2&index=7)

In the previous video of the series, the guy says that the vertex shader is run 3 times (for a triangle) and the fragment shader is run once for every pixel within the shape however in the video I have linked, there is nothing telling the vertex shader to run 3 times and there is nothing telling the fragment shader to be run multiple times either. Can someone please explain why?

Also I am struggling to understand the terminology being used. For example, in the vertex shader is the code: `in vec4 position` . And in the fragment shader there is the code `out vec4 color`. I searched around google alot for what this means but I couldn't find what it means anywhere.

Comment: You could at least show some effort by posting the code instead of referring to some ~30min Youtube video.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to add the time where the code is visible I will do that now

Comment: Not my downvote, but please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode if you want to know why you get downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**

A vertex shader is executed for each vertex of the primitives that need to be drawn. Since only a triangle (i.e. primitive with three vertices) is being drawn in the example, the vertex shader is obviously executed three times, once for each vertex of that triangle. The scheduling of the vertex shaders is done by OpenGL itself. The user does not need to take care of this.

A fragment shader is executed for each fragment generated by the rasterizer (i.e. the rasterizer breaks primitives down into discrete elements called *fragments*). A fragment corresponds to a pixel. Though this is not a bijection, for some pixels there can be no fragments and for some pixels there can be more than one fragment depending on the scene to draw. The scheduling of the fragments is done by OpenGL itself. The user does not need to take care of this.

The user effectively only configures the configurable stages of the pipeline, binds the programmable shaders, binds the shader input and output resources, and binds the geometry resources (vertex and index buffers, topology). The latter corresponds in the example to the vertex buffer containing the three vertices of the triangle, and the `GL_TRIANGLES` topology.

So given the example:

```
// The buffer ID.
unsigned int buffer;
// Generate one buffer object:
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
// Bind the newly created buffer to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target:
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
// Copies the previously defined vertex data into the buffer's memory:
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// Set the vertex attributes pointers
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);

...

// Bind the buffer as a vertex buffer:
glBindVertexArray(buffer);

...

// Draw a triangle list for the triangles with the vertices at indices [0,3) = 1 triangle:
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

A similar well-explained ["How to draw a triangle"-tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle).

**2.**

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
```

A user-defined input value to a [vertex shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader) (i.e. vertex attribute) of type `vec4` (a vector of 4 `float`s) with name `position`. In the example, each vertex has a `position` which needs to be transformed properly in the vertex shader before passing *eventually* to the rasterizer (assignment to `gl_Position`).

**3.**

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color
```

A user-defined output value to a [fragment shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) of type `vec4` (a vector of 4 `float`s) with name `color`. In the example, the fragment shader outputs a constant color (e.g., red) for each fragment to be *eventually* written to the back buffer.

**References**

Some useful OpenGL/GLSL reference:

- [Learn OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/)

And if you want to skip all CPU boiler plate and just focus on the shaders themselves, you can take a look at [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) to facilitate prototyping.

Comment: ok so what is an output value, what is an input value, and what is the difference between an output and an input value?

Comment: @adamtheguy762 The graphics pipeline consists of different connected stages of which the output of one stage is roughly the input of the next stage. Some of these stages are called shaders which can be programmed by the user. The user needs to define the desired input and output values of these shaders. The most common and basic setup consists of a vertex and fragment shader. The user needs to specify the input and output values of both of these shaders. The pipeline will pass the input values and the shader will generate some output values based on these input values.

Comment: Ok so I thought about that and then I realised that position will be an input to the vertex shader but then also an output because then it will be passed on to the rasterizer but only in is used for position. Also with the color in the fragment shader, why is that an output?

Comment: The vertex shader will output a position by assigning to `gl_Position`, which is a built-in (i.e. not user-defined) GLSL value for expressing the position in homogeneous space. The rasterizer always needs such a value per vertex (e.g., culling, clipping, etc.) To know where to find it, a special built-in variable is used. The red color in the fragment shader in the example is an output, since you want to draw a red triangle.